# Como atualizar Dados de um Select com Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tenho a seguinte duvida, tenho uma modal, onde insiro uma cidade, feito isso preciso que meu select seja recarregado mostrando essa opção recém adicionada, sem que a página seja atualizada:
Select:

```html
<select id="idMunicipio" name="idMunicipio" class="form-control">
  <?php foreach ($municipios as $municipio) : ?>
  <option value="<?=$municipio->idMunicipio?>"><?=$municipio->municipio?></option>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione-o ao `<select>` desejado. Basta inserir um elemento `<option>`.

**CÓDIGO**

Essa seria uma requisição POST para fazer a inserção do município. Quero que *se atente apenas a função de callback*. 
Supondo que o retorno da requisição seja um JSON da forma `{"id_municipio": "...", "nome_municipio": "..."}` então poderemos fazer o seguinte código:

```
$.post('algum_caminho', dadosMunicipio, function(data){
  $('select[name=idMunicipio]').append('<option value="'+data.id_municipio+'">'+data.nome_municipio+'</option>');
});
```

Onde **algum_caminho** seria para onde seria enviada a requisição (um arquivo PHP por exemplo), **dadosMunicipio** seriam os dados passados via requisição, coletados pela modal.